# Node Mysql Query in forEach Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to create an AWS Lambda function that collects data from an API and updates an RDS database.

The problem I'm having is that when I iterate over the data, the **connection.query** only ever recognizes the first record in the set. I'm assuming it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the connection, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

If I comment out the connection.query portion of the code, the console.log(sen.last_name) iterates properly.

```
const https = require('https');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

async function connect() {
    return await mysql.createConnection({
        host: "RDS_HOST",
        user: "RDS_USER",
        password: "RDS_PASS",
        database: "RDS_DB"
    }); 
}

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let connection = await connect()
    let congress = await getCongress();
    let body = JSON.parse(congress.body);
    let senators = body.results[0].members

    await asyncForEach(senators, async (sen) => {
        console.log(sen.last_name)
        await connection.query("INSERT INTO new_table (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('" + sen.id + "', '" + sen.first_name + "', '" + sen.last_name + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE first_name = '" + sen.first_name + "', last_name = '" + sen.last_name + "';", function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                connection.destroy();
                throw error;
            } else {
                // connected!
                console.log(results);
                callback(error, results);
                connection.end(function (err) { callback(err, results);});
            }
        });
    })

    return 'Done';
};
```

The function log that results is:

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: af04a976-9dae-424a-98cb-b60368c1fd29 Version: $LATEST
2020-06-08T03:34:32.801Z    af04a976-9dae-424a-98cb-b60368c1fd29    INFO    Alexander
2020-06-08T03:34:32.864Z    af04a976-9dae-424a-98cb-b60368c1fd29    INFO    ResultSetHeader {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  info: '',
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningStatus: 0
}
```

**---UPDATE---**

So it appears this has something to do with the connection not persisting through the entire loop. If I remove

```
connection.end(function (err) { callback(err, results);});
```

I just end up getting another error that says it timed out after 3 seconds.

What worked for me was chaging the connection to a pool, which does not need to be asynchronous apparently:

```
function connect() {
    return mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 1, //important
        host: "RDS_HOST",
        user: "RDS_USER",
        password: "RDS_PASS",
        database: "RDS_DB"
    });
}
```

And then just looping through the results normally:

```
for (const sen of senators) {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO new_table (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE first_name = ?, last_name = ?;"
    await pool.query(sql, [sen.id, sen.first_name, sen.last_name, sen.first_name, sen.last_name], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results);
    });
}
```

I also noticed I had to use prepared statements to get it to accept more than one query, which I assume is a safety feature.

I'm still very unclear on exactly why the pool works (even with a connection limit of 1) while the connection doesn't. So if anybody wants to chime in on that, please do so.

Comment: It looks like each time through your loop, you're inserting a senator and then calling `connection.end`. Judging from the method name, I wonder if this is what's ending your interaction with the database once an item is inserted.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be it. If I remove it or move it elsewhere, I get:  "errorMessage": ... Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"

Comment: Why would a library that is named *mysql2/promise* have methods that take callbacks? Do not pass a callback when you expect it to return an `await`able promise!